# PHP Mass Mailling with authentification

Tags: php, massmail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use php mass mailer or simply mail()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120126/use-php-mass-mailer-or-simply-mail)

Hello,

What is the best way to send 3000 emails (for example) with PHP?
I understand using mail() function is not the recommended solution and that authentication with the MX server is a best practice.

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+mass+mailing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+bulk+mail

Comment: Must-read http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html (language independent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) would be a big help