# EMAIL from web server

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-email, email-spam

We have a website sending mail alerts to end users. The site has been developed in c# ASP.NET.

I want to find the best way to send the email alerts to my users. Making sure the mail is not trapped in any spam filters. I read on the internet it is best to sent the mail directly from the web server and not route via an SMTP mail service such as google apps or Postini.

Can anyone tell me if this is correct?

Comment: I know that if an email is good written, this is not mark as spam. I build a web site where mail are sent using an SmtpClient, my collegue wrote a well formatted message. The first tests catch error because all request was marked as spam, but after modify email contet all work fine (sorry for bad english, i'm italian).

Comment: Sending e-mail is easy, getting it delivered is hard. There is no general rule that works every time - the host sending the message is relevant, but so are other parameters (mail content, mail volume, proper antispam headers, etc.). For a high e-mail traffic, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734/how-to-send-100-000-emails-weekly/3905805#3905805

Comment: All you need for simple sending of e-mails: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to not actually send email and let someone else deal with the problem. I'd look at [postmark](http://postmarkapp.com/) or Amazon's [simple email service](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/).

Answer (score 3):

First of all

> Making sure the mail is not trapped in
>   any spam filters

Is not possible - otherwise spammers would do this.  You just have to make sure you're domain isn't associated with any spamming activities and watch for keywords within the email.

> I read on the internet it is best to
>   sent the mail directly from the web
>   server and not route via an SMTP mail
>   service such as google apps or
>   Postini.

This point doesn't make sense - your e-mail will never be delivered if it doesn't get routed via an SMTP server, the average message will pass through multiple on its route to the recipient.

Comment: thank you for the comment. I guess this was not phrased very well. Point taken

Answer (score 0):

We had problems that mails sent with local server often get trapped in spam filters until we implemented SPF on our mail server.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework

But I am not admin, that's just what our admin said, and after that we have no problems anymore.

btw. maybe would be better to ask on serverfault.com

Comment: Thank you for the good advice. I will post a more detailed question on serverfault.com