# How to send validation email without going into the spam folder?

Tags: php, email, email-spam

I have a PHP website that send a validation code when a new account is created.

My problem is since few months, a lot of those email goes in the spam folder.

I thought of a solution that is to use an "external service" to send my email instead of simply sending it via the mail function in PHP.

Question : 1) What external service should I use (I guess it would requires to have an API)?

Comment: If the headers is not set properly OR sending a lot of mails in once  can be causes to get mail in spam

Comment: Not everything from that list is applicable, but check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734/how-to-send-100-000-emails-weekly/3905805#3905805 . TL;DR: there is no way that you can make sure your e-mail won't be marked as spam, there are some tricks that improve your chances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using your ISP's or company's server as a relay.  Use a sending address which exists, so that validation can be done on it, and bounces sent back to it.  You may want to setup a separate domain for verification such as `verification.example.com`.   You could then send the validation message from `application@verification.example.com`.  Replace application and example as appropriate.

You may also want to look at https://serverfault.com/questions/241189/email-delivery-management-grievances#241260.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [this](https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=81126) documentation from Google.  It involves your network support including reverse lookup and Domain keys to be present.  I think most of the email servers would have similar requisites.

Answer (score 1):

Many times, when using the builtin `mail` function, the configuration isn't set up to help prevent this from happening. The reason is the *Received* header is set to an internal IP address, like 192.168.x.x which is used as an indicator to most spam filters. You may want to try finding a simple SMTP class that connects remotely so the headers get set properly.

Comment: I have checked and the Receive header does not contain an internal IP but the IP of the VPS. Thank you for the tips.

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck finding a solution that works for you.