# Gmail is marking PHP emails as spam

Tags: php, email-spam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to send validation email without going into the spam folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169354/how-to-send-validation-email-without-going-into-the-spam-folder)

I have this PHP server that sends verification emails to the users.

Whenever the system sends a verify verifcation to a user, GMAIL marks it as spam. 
What do I need to do to make it stop? It is hard for me to explain to the clients what to do and it is not right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not PHP, its the SMTP server you're sending from.

Even until recently, [sugarsync](http://sugarsync.com) emails still get spam filtered by gmail.

Answer (score 1):

You should ensure that the subject of the email or body doesn't include any irrelevant text that could be interpreted as spam?