# Sending mass email in MVC-3

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am building an MVC3 app that will require sending a mass email from a list.  This isn't used for spamming, but rather a legitimate list of volunteers from the medical community.

Is there an example of using MVC-3 to send mass emails, including using a queue system so that the server doesn't become overloaded?

Thanks!

Comment: look for detailed info here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5902723/313378. Maybe you'll found it useful.

Comment: Approximately how many recipients are you talking about? One thing you need to consider is whether the recipients email providers (e.g. Hotmail, GMail, etc.) are going to mark your email as spam. Sending a lot of emails to the same email provider in a short time frame could look spam-like. If you're sending thousands of emails, you might have issues. Maybe even hundreds of emails will cause a problem. I'm not sure what the specific threshold rules are -- email providers keep their limits sort of secret so that real spammers can't just game their rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending email lists isn't as easy as it used to be.

I suggest you use something like [Socket Labs' Hurricane Server](http://www.socketlabs.com/hms)

It's free for up to 500 emails per month