# Is sending mails through SMTP better than php mail() in terms of server load?

Tags: php, email, smtp, server-load

I am sending >1000 mails per day for a mailing list. Right now they are all sent with php mail(). Would it put less load on the server if they were sent through a script with SMTP ?

Comment: This might also be of interest, should you decide to send even more e-mails: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734/how-to-send-100-000-emails-weekly/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really, no: the mail needs to go through SMTP anyway, so you're just changing how it gets there (on some hosts, `mail()` uses SMTP internally, anyway). If the server is highly loaded while sending, could it be something *else* in your script that's generating the load?

Comment: It could potentially take longer to use an external SMTP connection, since it would have to take time to connect to that host. I'm not sure how this would play out performance-wise, but the requests themselves would probably take longer.

Comment: @DesignerGuy: I was assuming the SMTP server would be on localhost, or on local network. Assuming a server "out there somewhere", it would take longer, yes; OTOH, thus spreading the requests out might help with the load.

Comment: Got it. Ya, it is hard to say.

Comment: @mike23 - You should try it out and monitor the load. You should be able to tell relatively quickly if it is better or not.