# loop sending email cakephp

Tags: cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

I want to send emails to different users like the email I use 
the problem is that it takes a long time

```
foreach($users as $user){

$this->Email->smtpOptions = array(
                              'port' => '25',
                              'timeout' => '30',
                              'host' => 'smtp.topnet.tn',
                           );
            Envoie Mail 
            $this->Email->delivery = 'smtp';

            $this->Email->reset();
            $this->Email->from = $from;
            $this->Email->to = $To;
            $this->Email->subject = $subject;
            $this->set('id_user',$user_id);
            $this->set('password',$pass);
            $this->Email->template = 'activcompte';

            $this->Email->sendAs = 'both';

           $this->Email->send();
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind if you are sending to > 1000 users, you may want to read up on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734/how-to-send-100-000-emails-weekly Mass mailing is a non-trivial business best left up to the pros

Comment: You could try to set a cron for it. Whenever your server becomes free, set that time to run the above code.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the foreach loop to send the mail to all the users one by one, simply make an array of all the users..like...

```
  $Recepients[0] => abc@gmail.com
  $Recepients[1] => def@gmail.com
  $Recepients[2] => ghi@gmail.com
  ....

 and then assign this "$Recepients" array
```

$this->Email->to = $Recepients;