# How to send automated e-mails using server-side language

Tags: javascript, asp.net, email, html-email

I would like to send an automated e-mail to my clients on their birthday. Is there a library or a good place to find template code for doing something like this? I've used SMTP in the past, but that was for iOS development. I am looking for something using JS or .NET (or maybe even HTML?) to do this. I am only guessing that it will need to be server-side because it needs to run automatically, pulling birthdays from the database.

Has anyone used certain methods that they have found particularly effective? Thanks

Comment: Look at the SmtpClient class.  It has what you need.  There are endless examples on how to use this class.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx

Comment: hopefully this wont apply to you, but just in case, you may want to have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734/how-to-send-100-000-emails-weekly

Comment: Did you Google this before asking? Googling ".NET sending email" returns several articles about how to send email through .NET APIs. Research before you ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a simple example of sending mail with .NET'S [SMTPClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx)

```
using (System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mailMessage = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage())
 {

  mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(toAddress ));

  mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(fromAddress, nameToAppearFrom);

  mailMessage.Subject = subject;
  mailMessage.Body = messageText;
  mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

  SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
  smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;

  smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
}
```

In order to use this you would also need `Using System.Net.Mail ;` in your code file
and in your web config you would need

```
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="from address">
        <network host="yourt mail server" defaultCredentials="false" port="port#" userName="username" password="password"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

Alternatively depending on the database engine you are using you could also send mail from the database, this could be in the form of a daily job that gets all people with birthdays and then calls a mail function/stored procedure