# Can the GAE email limit go over 20,000?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm thinking about building an email app on GAE but worried about the email quota limit.  Can I continue to grow the quota over 20,000?  And if so is there a limit or can I grow it over time?

Comment: Are you reinventing the whee--MailChimp?

Comment: Actually yes because MailChimp keeps shutting down our account from illegitimate claims.

Comment: before you invest your time and code using GAE's mail servers, you should be aware of the severe limitations they impose.  http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1800

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about GAE terms of service, not programming.

Comment: @BilltheLizard

somehow google officially declared stackoverflow is the place to ask development question, it didn't said it must be programming question.

see
https://developers.google.com/appengine/community

Comment: @LarryMok Google doesn't decide what's on-topic here, we do. If you have a question about Google's terms of service, it makes sense to ask Google, not us. This site is for programming questions.

Comment: @BilltheLizard May be it's Google's fault then. They ask the developer to come here and say their team will be here to answer question. And there is no where else we can contact the team.

Answer (score 4):

Of course you can:

From: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Mail

> If your app will need to send more than 20,000 messages per day,
>   consider signing up for a premier account.

I'm sure you've got great amount of user and could afford the price if you have that much email to send.

Answer (score 1):

You can't with a standard account, but usually a limit of 20,000 emails/day is enough (I guess this limit is to prevent spammers to use their API).

If you want to send more, you should look for a third-party service or you can try to contact the GAE sales team, I know that they give higher quotas for some of their customers

Comment: Thanks for the info.  20,000 is not enough if you have mailing lists with more emails than that.

Comment: I know, but I mean that their API is more for contact or validation emails. Never try to send emails to large mailing lists yourself, you will run into a lot of issues. Check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734/how-to-send-100-000-emails-weekly

Comment: I would normally agree with you, but I've out grown third party services and I'm to the point now where I need to control the process more.  So I'm going to do the list management myself and use a service like GAE or Amazon SES to actually send the mail.

Looks like Amazon SES wins because GAE can't handle the amount I'll need.

Comment: You can also try to contact the GAE sales team, I know that they give higher quotas for some of their customers.