# Laravel not able to fetch more than 8000 records

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel problem while fetching record from the database.

`laravel get()` not able to fetch **8000 record**. I am using `$this->query->get();`. I have set some filters on `$this->query` so i only want solution for this one statement only. Also i have already tried **take()** method but did not get the solution.

Comment: No offense, but why do you need to take/display 8000 rows at one time? Is it not possible to process this number of rows on database server in this situation? Just give more info, so that we can help you solve this problem.

Comment: Actually i want to get all 80000 users email id and some info so that i can set a program to mail all the user at one execution.

Comment: Most mailing implementations have a limit on how many recipients you can have in one email. 80000 is probably way above that limit anyways :-D

Comment: So 8 000, or 80 000?
I definitely would not send 80 000 at once. Sending emails is time consuming, and your (sender) email address gets blacklisted, probably (too many emails in short timespan). It's even possible your host wont allow you to send such number of emails. I would create some CRON which take several addresses and send emails (100 emails every 10 minutes, or so...)

Comment: It might be a problem with your memory limits, you can try to raise them, and see if you can get more users then. And you should specify the fields you want to retrieve so you will have less overhead.

Comment: I agree with the above commenters. That being said, we don't have enough information to know what your error specifically is to help, in that case that you do in fact need to grab 80,000(!) records at once. What error message do you get? Server memory limit reached?

Comment: Actually problem are in Laravel get() function, when i write $this->query->count(); it returns me no of record, but when using get() not returning any thing.

Answer (score 3):

With the above comments/concerns in mind, I suggest that you (perhaps, via a Cron Job) fetch 1000 at a time, and split your emails into batches.

So, you'd first fetch 1000 records. From those, you would send 100 emails every ten minutes, as per [Andreyco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/563807/andreyco)'s suggestion. Then, you'd wait for another ten minutes, and repeat the process for the next 1000 records, until the process is complete.

However, I highly suggest making use of a [High Volume Mailchimp account](http://www.mailchimp.com/pricing/high-volume). This is the preferred method, and much safer for your email account/domain.

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3905805/1626250) for more clarification and information.

It must be noted that each server has its own memory limits, and that working with that many records at once is not normal.