# send simple email via Mailchimp with PHP

Tags: php, web-services, email, mailchimp

i want to send emails to my users in my PHP project. i do this but sometime my emails goes to spam folder...

because of that i want to use Mailchimp but i cant find any example of how to use it.

i downloaded PHP APIwrapper but i cant use. i don't need to send html mails. i just send simple text. how i can do this? i just want my email don't goes to spam folder

Comment: That isn't the point of MailChimp.  Look at SendGrid.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3905734/34397