# Sending Mass emails from another server

Tags: php, phpmailer, remote-server, spam-prevention, massmail

I have two servers,ServerA & ServerB.ServerA do not support mass mailing while ServerB do support(I have more than 4000 email addresses in MySQL table).

On ServerA I am creating HTML for emails and On ServerB I put script to send emails.I run this code on ServerA

```
ob_end_clean();
header("Connection: close");
ignore_user_abort(); // optional
ob_start();
echo ('Sending email...');
$size = ob_get_length();
header("Content-Length: $size");
ob_end_flush();     // Will not work
flush();            // Unless both are called !
$postdata = http_build_query(
array(
    'subject'=>'Latest Rentals Properties',
    'message' => $message   //email body html
     )
);
$opts = array('http' =>
array(
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'content' => $postdata
     )
  );
$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$result = @file_get_contents('http://ServerB.com/send_email.php', false, $context);
if($http_response_header[0]=="HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found"):echo "404";
elseif($http_response_header[0]=="HTTP/1.1 200 OK"):echo "OK";
else "ERROR";
```

On ServerB.com,send_email.php has this code to send email(I am using class.phpmailer.php)

```
$subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
$message1 = $_REQUEST['message'];
$mail->SetFrom("from@ServerB.com", '');
$rs = $oBj->query("SELECT email FROM `crm_test_emails` where is_active = 1 ");
while ( $rw = $oBj->row($rs) ){
$email= $rw['email'];
$message1         = str_replace("########",$email,$message1);
$mail->AddAddress($email, "");
$mail->Subject    = $subject;
$mail->MsgHTML($message1);
$mail->Send();
}
```

My questions are

1. One email address getting more than 500 same emails(sending duplicates).
2. Email goes directly to spam.
3. I do not want any one to see others emails.Right now one email id can see all others to whom i sent email.

I asked questions on priority,first one is more important and so on..
Please guide me where i have issue in code logic.

Comment: In this case is maybe better to use some external e-mail services like MailChimp. Otherwise you have a very long way to reach what you want.

Comment: clearAddresses()  would solve 1 and 3 call it at the top of the loop

Comment: Still not fixed...I am waiting for some one to help me out...

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest using a service such as http://www.mailgun.com/. Mass email sending requires a huge amount of effort to get it right (see [How to send 100,000 emails weekly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734/how-to-send-100-000-emails-weekly)).

Mailgun gives the first 10,000 emails free every month so this service would be free if you were sending these emails once or twice a month. If you do send them weekly, their prices are really cheap anyway.

Comment: Whats wrong with my code?I tried few services but there were alot of issues,they asked about the source of emails etc etc

Comment: If you can't reply about source of your addresses than you're asking for troubles. Read the links above (especially the 100K emails weekly) and think for a while where are you now and where you want to go.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Subscribe](https://github.com/zonito/subscribe) - Open-source project - a service which helps you in setting up Mail Sender application using [GAE](http://code.google.com/appengine).

Its easy to install.

#### Why Subscribe?

- Handles multiple applications. Just add your application's specific private key. It will handle all your unsubscriptions application wise.
- Handles multiple sender depending on your type of mails. Add all sender's email address in your appengine application.
- No need to handle your unsubscriptions while sending emails to your customers / users. Service already taking care of it. Append's unsubscribe link along with given body.

Answer (score -1):

**for question one** i m checking your code

**for question 2** 
You need to make sure your email signing server is has same domain name as you sending email address any ways this is a long topic some details are here

http://sendgrid.com/blog/10-tips-to-keep-email-out-of-the-spam-folder/

**for question 3**

please add all address to BCC Addressees not main address send email as Blind copy

Comment: `BCC` can still be read so you will pretty much give out your list of emails which is not good.

Comment: @Prix please increase you knowledge read this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_carbon_copy

Comment: Looks like reading is not your strong point, from your own link, **attention to the latter part after the last comma:** `Depending on email software, the tertiary recipients may only see their own email address in Bcc, or they may see the email addresses of all recipients.`

Comment: To and cc, yes. But not bcc though.