# How to send 100000 mail using PHP

Tags: php

I have used below code:

```
<?php
$file = fopen("contacts.csv","r");
while(! feof($file))
{
$age=fgetcsv($file);
foreach($age as $x_value) 
{
$to = $x_value;
$subject = "HTML email";
$message = "<html><head><title>HTML email</title></head><body>here ismessage</body></html>";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: <abc@example.com>' . "\r\n";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
}
}
fclose($file);
?>
```

I tried this, but this will not work because this is not secure. So what method should I use?

Comment: Sounds like you are asking to build a spam-distributor. Please elaborate the question by explaining *why*  you want to send such a large number of e-mails and what you have already tried to do this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send 100,000 emails weekly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734/how-to-send-100-000-emails-weekly)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Email Sending Service such as Amazon Simple Email Service. https://aws.amazon.com/ses/

They will charge you for the service, but the costs are very affordable: $0.1 per thousand emails

The integration with cakephp is pretty easy, but you will need to use the CakeEmail Library and use SMTP Transport.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html