# Send tons of email by message queue

Tags: message-queue

I have 1 million addresses in table, and 1 function to send mail to all.
The scenario i thought is make 1 task to select all 1 million emails then send one by one OR split into smaller tasks to (such as 2 tasks with 500k emails for each).
But how i manage the log when it is fail when sent to some emails.
I don't any mail module to support. I just want to know the logic.
**Edit:** not only email but my app also have our notification system, do it in same way for email.

Comment: it not a real case but i want to know how i should implement when i be asked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send 100,000 emails weekly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734/how-to-send-100-000-emails-weekly)

Comment: what i should i do when my `for` loop crash when still sending

Comment: i assume not using any third module, user may have email or not, or email  not correct, i have to log all

Answer (score 1):

Use a legitimate bulk mail service like SendGrid.com, MailGun, etc.

If you use your own web hosted server it probably can't handle the traffic and has a good chance of ending up blacklisted so all outgoing mail will be blocked.

Comment: how about our notification system, only internal

Comment: How many notifications, how many users,, and what kind of data?  Would something like an RSS feed work?  A staff portal or website?

Comment: data now only text, it lock like notification people got in facebook

Comment: For staff mail boxes on the same server, your mail idea is much more likely to work than trying to bulk mail to customers.  You probably do not have 1 million staff members :)  .  If you use BCC then you do not need to send 100 single emails you can just send 1.